# How to use Azure Repos app on MS teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a repository on Azure DevOps and I would like to monitor its commits with MS Teams. 
There seem to be [a specific MS Teams extension for that](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzureDevOpsChatOps.AzureRepos-TeamsApp).

I cannot get it to work by any means, after the app is installed through the "Application" menu, nothing happens, I'm clueless on how to set it up

[image]

On top of the MS teams interface, I have this bar that confirms Azure Repo is installed, but whatever I type in, nothing shows up. Nothing allows me to configure anything, I really feel like this app is either completely broken, or I'm totally missing the way those app should be configured.

- I can only install/uninstall the app through the Application panel, there's no configuration menu
- Clicking on the ellipsis (...) in the top bar only asks me to choose a repository, nothing happens after that
- Searching for commit hashes yield nothing
- Azure Repo doesn't show up in my conversations even after restarting MS Teams completely
- Clicking Apps dashboard > Azure Repos > Open, does absolutely nothing

How can I use Azure Repos MS teams app to monitor my repository ?

Comment: I have experienced something similar. The functionality doesn't seem to match the documentation at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/integrations/repos-teams?view=azure-devops - It appears that it's only allowing you to search pull requests.

Comment: I have the same issues and the answers below nor the documentation doesn't help. It has been setup by another colleague but I cannot figure a way to configure it with those commands. Still can't figure out where to type them.

Answer (score 1):

I was just trying to solve this and found solution to this. When installing azure app (and even when already installed) you can open dropdown menu that is on a Add/Open button (right side)
There you will have an option to add app to team after which the bot will be initialized and you can follow the guide you posted

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Ilienoraes worked for me, I'm just adding details.

In Teams, open the App install menu
[image]

Click on the context menu next to the Open button and select Add to a team
[image]

Anter a team name
[image]

And the bot will be installed
[image]

Comment: … and after that, you can set up notification subscriptions.

Comment: But then what? I don't get it. Where do you send the "commands"? If I type `@Azure Repos signin` at the top then before I even get to finish writing it has started seaching for pull requests (it finds none). What (specifically) do you do to sign in?

Comment: Oh wait you're supposed to add it as a comment to the post of Azure Repos.

Comment: Another thing is, don't paste commands like `@Azure Repos subscribe`. You need Teams to resolve Azure Repos, so you have to type the command.

Comment: How do you configure it after this has been installed? This procedure doesn't work when it has already been installed. This documentation here is not helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/integrations/repos-teams?view=azure-devops